# How to log into WordPress via GET/POST

Tags: wp-admin, login, dashboard, hacked

I have an old WordPress site, which I have no FTP access or anything and in WP-Login.php I'm getting this message.

But I remember my login credentials, mail and password.

Is there anyway I could bypass this login screen which is disabled?

Perhaps logging via a POST method or something like that?

Any idea?

Thanks!

[image: Message on login page (wp-login.php)]

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the plugins folder (in wp-content), but since you have no FTP access, that is harder. If you have File Manager access via your hosting cPanel, use that to rename the folder.

But no bypass of a login via a GET/POST - that would be a serious security problem.

Most likely, a plugin (or maybe some code in your theme's function.php file) is changing the login process. You will need File Manager access of some sort to get to the files that are causing the problem.